# Why c++ puts same-named variables defined in separate modules into same address in memory?

Tags: c++, g++

Let's take header file `var.h`

```
#include <iostream>

class var
  {public:
      var () {std::cout << "Creating var at " << this << std::endl; }
      ~var () {std::cout << "Deleting var at " << this << std::endl; }
  };
```

and two source files, first `lib.cpp`

```
#include "var.h"
var A;
```

and second `app.cpp`

```
#include "var.h"

var A;

int main ()
  {return 0;
  }
```

then, if I attempt to compile them

```
g++ -c app.cpp
g++ -c lib.cpp
g++ -o app app.o lib.o
```

linker return multiply defined variable error. But, if I compile it onto shared library + main app

```
g++ -fPIC -c lib.cpp
g++ --shared -o liblib.so lib.o
g++ -fPIC -c app.cpp
g++ -o app -llib -L . app.o
```

it links without error. However program doesn't work properly:

```
./app
Creating var at 0x6013c0
Creating var at 0x6013c0
Deleting var at 0x6013c0
Deleting var at 0x6013c0
```

so different variables was created at the same memory address! It might put into serious trouble, for example, in a case when library and application expect them to have different values (values of object fields in this case).

if `class var` do memory allocation/deleting valgrind warns about accessing memory in recently deleted block.

Yes, I know I could put `static var A;` instead of `var A;` and both ways to compile will work properly. My question is: why one can't use same-named variables (or even functions?) in different libraries? Library creators might know nothing about names each other use and not to be warned to use `static`. Why GNU linked doesn't warn about this conflict?

And, BTW, could `dlload` put into same trouble?

UPD. Thank you all for explaining about namespaces and extern, I see why same symbols are placed into same memory address, but still I can't get why no linking error or even warning about doubly defined variable is shown but wrong code produced in second case.

Answer (score 5):

> My question is: why one can't use same-named variables (or even functions?) 
>   in different libraries?

You can. The thing you're missing is that the declarations

```
var A;
```

aren't defining the symbol `A` for use in the library. They're defining the symbol to be exported for so that any other compilation unit can reference it!

e.g. if, in `app.cpp`, you declared

```
extern var A;
```

this would mean declare "`A` is a variable of type `var` that some other compilation unit is going to define and export" -- with this modification to your setup, this would make `app.cpp` explicitly request to use the object named `A` that `lib.cpp` exported.

The problem with your setup is that you have two different compilation units both trying to export the same symbol `A`, which leads to a conflict.

```
Why GNU linked doesn't warn about this conflict?
```

Because GNU can't know that you wanted `A` to be a variable private to your compilation unit unless you *tell* GNU that it should be private to your compilation unit. That's what `static` means in this context.

Comment: Oh, I've got about extern, it should work through libraries shouldn't it? But I'm still confused why linker provide invalid code without warning after all...

Comment: That I don't know. Alas, I don't have enough knowledge of shared libraries and gcc to know if you're simply not supposed to use them in this fashion (and thus it's on your own head if you get weird behavior), or if this is an actual bug in GCC.

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear if you're asking whether this is supposed to happen or what the rationale is.

First, it is required behavior. Per the "one definition rule", section 3.2 of the C++ standard, if multiple translation units contain identical definitions (and certain other requirements are met), then the program shall behave as if there were a single definition. In any other case where there are multiple definitions, the behavior is undefined.

If you're asking what the rationale for this rule is, it's that it's usually what you want. Your compiler may have an option to alert if more than one definition isn't marked `extern`.

Comment: Just to be clear, he's not meeting those other requirements, and he's seeing UB.

Answer (score 2):

Different libraries should have differently named *global* variables and *global* functions, otherwise very unpleasant things happen (e.g. when `dlopen`-ing it several times...).

Conventionally, well behaved libraries use a common prefix (like `gtk`) in C, or a namespace in C++.

And libraries should minimize global state (in C++, it probably should be static data inside classes).

You could also use the `visibility` [function attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) accepted by GCC.

Answer (score 1):

Symbols with `extern` linkage (which is the default in this case) are visible to other translation units. This is to allow interfaces between source files, libraries, etc.

The existence or non-existence of a definition does not change which object is accessed. The programmer is responsible for arranging declarations and definitions such that an object always declared before use and always defined exactly once (the one-definition rule).

The best solution is to put private globals into unnamed namespaces, so that definitions that look the same can still be different.

lib.cpp

```
#include "var.h"
namespace { // unnamed namespace
    var A; // object inaccessible to other translation units
}
```

app.cpp

```
#include "var.h"

namespace { // different unnamed namespace
    var A; // different object
}

int main ()
  {return 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat simplified answer: "libraries" are an implementation detail.  All object files are combined (linked) to a *single* unit (executable) *prior* to execution.  After linking has been done, there is no trace of libraries, original source files, etc. any longer -- all that matters is the final executable.

Now, you seem to be surprised that the same global name in the program (= the final result of linikng everything together) always refers to the same object.  Wouldn't it be confusing if it were otherwise?

If file1.cpp and file2.cpp both defined a variable `A` with external linkage, how are the compiler and linker supposed to know whether you want one or two different objects?  More importantly, how is the *human* reading the code supposed to know whether the original author wanted to create one or two objects?

Comment: You're not allowed to *define* the same object twice. You can *declare* it twice, though. His program is ill-formed, since `A` should name the same object in both translation units, and both units also *define* `A`. The oddity is that GCC rightfully complains in his first build, but doesn't complain in his second build.

Comment: Well, you ARE allowed to have `int A;` in multiple object files, and there won't be any linker errors. Anyway, as I said, it is somewhat simplified/imprecise answer.

Comment: Hurkyl is right, the question is why gcc complains in first case and doesn't in second but produce an incorrect code.